# CSS grid responsive child element vertically and horizontally center item

Tags: html, css

How do you have a CSS grid that is responsive for its child container when centered horizontally and vertically, I want to do this with  CSS grid only. The code below doesn't work at all but it's the basics of what I want, can someone please get my code to work and make the box responsive, please!

```css
html,
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: remove html from the selector + box-sizing:border-box to child

Comment: When you say 'responsive', how do you expected an element with a fixed height of 500 pixels to respond on a screen that's 400 pixels heigh?

Comment: @Gerard it's the width that needs to be responsive it doesn't what size it is and your code doesn't work for the  css grid

Comment: @ONYX I'm surprised you are refering to my code, because I didn't post any.

Answer (score -1):

remove `html`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: it works but it's not correct way for my sample, so there needs to be another way to make CSS grid responsive

Comment: @ONYX what do you mean by *not correct way*?

Answer (score -2):

just remove HTML from your CSS target element cause HTML is the root element of your page

```
body {
      display: grid;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

<div class="box"></div>
```